# GeekTool won't run UNIX command that works in Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, php, geektool

Just to put an example, in the Terminal:

```
php -f file.php
```

Works perfectly, when I try to use this in GeekTool it just does not work.

It works fine till:

```
php -f
```

Displaying the possible option, but when I write: `file.php` it just doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get an error message? "Does not work" is not very informative.

Comment: @Denis, Sorry about that, the thing is nothing happes really... just blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either php isn't found or file.php isn't found. Use the full path, or "cd" to the folder where file.php is.

Comment: Thanks mankoff! It was exactly that! I had to 'cd' to the file. Thank you very much!